# Fancybox 2 does not work from link within table data

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I am using fancybox 2 to open a vimeo video. The link works fine when is not in the table, but not when I have the link inside the  table with font-awesome icon. The video just opens in the full size browser and not as fancybox.

Here are the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>


<td><a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/139829820" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"> <i class="fa fa-play-circle  fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a></td>
```

I will be thankful for any suggestions.